# Facebook comment plugin code

Tags: facebook, plugins, comments

I've seen some post up already around the same subject but not really what I wanted to know

But i'm trying to add the facebook comment box plug in, into my site but it doesn't seem to be working, this is the code it has given me

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=***************";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>


<div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://www.facebook.com/pages/Cuba-Street/86653690342?fref=ts" data-num-posts="2" data-width="470"></div>
```

But it just doesn't seem to return anything?

Comment: Post your full code, the above code seems to be working fine, the problem could with your other codes.

Answer (score 0):

I checked your code without single modification, it works for me